# Salta excepción a pesar del try/catch,

Tags: java, excepciones, nullpointerexception, enum

Estoy creando un método que va a asignar a un atributo un valor de talla válido. Los valores de las tallas los tengo en un tipo enumerado. Y muestro el método que he diseñado para que el usuario introduzca el valor de la talla. El caso es que cuando introduzco un valor por teclado que no está recogido en el tipo enumerado salta una excepcion a pesar de que está recogida en el catch. Abajo indico el codigo de la excepcion que salta

```
private enum tallasArticulo {
    XS, S, M, L, XL, XXL
};

 public static String validarTalla(Scanner sc) {

        tallasArticulo t = null;
        
        String talla = null;

        do {

            System.out.println("Escribe la talla: ");

           
            try {
                talla = sc.next();
                
                t = tallasArticulo.valueOf(talla.toUpperCase());
                
                talla = t.toString();
                
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException il) {
                System.out.println(il.getMessage());
                System.out.println("Por favor introduce un valor correcto de talla: XS, S, M, L, XL, XXL ");
            } 
            catch (NullPointerException nulP){
                System.out.println(nulP.getMessage());
                System.out.println("Introduce un valor correcto de talla: XS, S, M, L, XL, XXL ");
            }       
            catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                System.out.println("Por favor introduce un valor correcto de talla");
            }           
            
        } while ((talla == null));

        return talla;
    }


Escribe la talla: 
8
No enum constant Validaciones.tallasArticulo.8
Por favor introduce un valor correcto de talla
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "Validaciones$tallasArticulo.toString()" because "t" is null
    at Validaciones.validarTalla(Validaciones.java:74)
    at Ticket.crearArticulo(Ticket.java:42)
    at Main.main(Main.java:32)
D:\PROGRAMACIÓN_DAM\UT10\ExmRafPere160421\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1366: The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\PROGRAMACIÓN_DAM\UT10\ExmRafPere160421\nbproject\build-impl.xml:961: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 30 seconds)
```

Comment: Está saltando un `NullPointerException`, no se recomienda capturar este tipo de excepciones, lo que deberías es controlar tu código haciéndolo *null safe*, es decir, verificando de algún modo aquellos objetos que podrían ser nulos.

Comment: Exacto el problema que detecta es que:  "t" is null. Pero no sé cómo hacer lo que dices. Por favor, puedes explicarlo un poco más o poner un link hacia donde puedo investigar lo que dices. Gracias

Comment: Creo que tu poblema es que es que cuando termina la primera iteración talla ya no es null, así que sale del while y termina. Prueba una cosa, en cada excepción pon `talla = null`, y mira a ver si te funciona.

Answer (score 1):

Debes introducir alguno de estos valores:

XS, S, M, L, XL, XXL

ya que tu mètodo `validarTalla()` internamente en este punto :

```
   t = tallasArticulo.valueOf(talla.toUpperCase());
```

obtiene un valor del enum:

```
 private enum tallasArticulo {
    XS, S, M, L, XL, XXL
};
```

Pero debes llamar de esta forma el mètodo `validarTalla()` :

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);  
    validarTalla(in);
```

Comment: Sí, la llamada al método la hago como dices, y como es estático escribo delante el nombre de la clase. De hecho salta la excepcion porque el método está funcionando.

Answer (score 1):

Aclaro que lo que está pasando no es que se salta la excepcion tal como describis. En tu código estas diciendo que cada vez que ocurra una excepción de tipo `NullPointerException` escribas por consola:

```java
catch (NullPointerException nulP){
    System.out.println(nulP.getMessage());
    System.out.println("Introduce un valor correcto de talla: XS, S, M, L, XL, XXL ");
}
```

Que es exactamente lo que esta retornando tu ejecución, primero el mensaje de la excepción:

> D:\PROGRAMACIÓN_DAM\UT10\ExmRafPere160421\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1366: The following error occurred while executing this line:

y luego tu mensaje personalizado:

> D:\PROGRAMACIÓN_DAM\UT10\ExmRafPere160421\nbproject\build-impl.xml:961: Java returned: 1

Esto podrías verlo mejor ejecutando en modo debug.

A su vez la ejecución del metodo **validarTalla()** termina porque sale del `while` ya que `talla` deja de ser `null` en el momento en que le asignaste 8 (en tu ejemplo) por consola.